# How to stop JMeter Thread in case of errors in specific requests (samplers)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

We have an option in ThreadGroup to stop or continue threads in case of errors. But this option applies to all the samplers within ThreadGroup.

Is there any way by which we can apply this condition only to specific samplers. For example, I have Login samplers in my test Plan and I want to stop those threads only which fail for login samplers.

Any possible workaround for that in JMeter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which must be successful and put the following code into "Script" area:

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
     prev.setStopThread(true);
}
```

where `prev` stands for associated parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using Beanshell in your JMeter tests

Comment: I had used an alternative approach that involved JMeter "Test Action". But your solution is much simpler and works great. thanks.

Comment: Am I guessing right that @Dmitri T is the main developer of Jmeter tool? :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you need to limit this behavior to one request, add a *Result Status Action Handler* as a child of the request

[image]

It's in post processor, then if it fails you can configure what happens, e.g. Stop the Thread from carrying on.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example of this in use?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

To ignore an expected 401 error on a specific request use this in an JSR223 PostProcessor:

```
if (prev.getResponseCode() == '401') {
    prev.setSuccessful(true)
}
```